# Display Image in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have an image and I want to create fragment and display this image but there's an error in Line.

> ImageView.setImageResource(AndroidImageAssete.getmeads.get(0));

Here's the code of my java file:

```
public class BodyPartFragment extends Fragment {

    public BodyPartFragment(){
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_body_part, container, false);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_body_part);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ImageView.setImageResource(AndroidImageAssete.getmeads.get(0));
        return rootView;

    }

}
```

And the main activity:

```
BodyPartFragment bodyPartFragment=new BodyPartFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.contener,contener);
        .commit();
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
/Users/mac/Downloads/Flagment/app/src/main/java/com/example/waadalkatheri/flagment/MainActivity.java
Error:(16, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 50.036 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: what is the logcat error? put logcat error here to better help

Comment: where is the image located? in drawable, mipmap, or on the web?

Comment: @Droidev in drawable

Comment: @BrunoFerreira i'm add the logcat error

Comment: what is the **compiler error output** error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
ImageView.setImageResource(AndroidImageAssete.getmeads.get(0));
```

with this line

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String imageFromDrawable = "@drawable/myresource";

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFromDrawable, null, getPackageName());

ImageView imageview = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
```